# Subgradient of projection distance function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient

I want to find subgradient of the function $f({\bf x}) = {\rm inf}_{{\bf y} \in \mathcal{C}} \|{\bf x} - {\bf y}\|_2$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed convex set.
Now, $f$ just measures the perpendicular distance from a point to its projection on the convex compact set $\mathcal{C}$.

I am not sure how a subgradient of the given function is to be calculated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a general result on the subdifferential of functions of the form $f(x)=\inf_{y\in\mathcal{C}}g(x,y)$, where $g$ is jointly convex in $(x,y)$. See Corollary 4.5.3 on page 273 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02796-7).